# SynchronizationContext.Current is null on resolving with Unity in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, system.reactive

I have a WPF Code which looks something like this.

```
public class AlphaProductesVM : BaseModel
{
    private  ObservableCollection<Alphabetical_list_of_product> _NwCustomers;
    private int i = 0;

    public AlphaProductesVM ()
    {
        _NwCustomers = new ObservableCollection<Alphabetical_list_of_product>();
        var repository = new NorthwindRepository();
           repository
               .GetAllProducts()
               .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
               .Subscribe(AddElement);
    }
    public void AddElements(IEnumerable<Alphabetical_list_of_product> elements)
    {
        foreach (var alphabeticalListOfProduct in elements)
        {
            AddElement(alphabeticalListOfProduct);
        }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<Alphabetical_list_of_product> NwCustomers
    {
        get { return _NwCustomers; }
        set { _NwCustomers = value; }
    }}
```

I use Unity to Resolve the above `AlphaProductesVM`. This is instant when the Module is discovered using PRISM and the UnityBootstrapper. At runtime `.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)` throws an exception and `SynchronizationContext.Current` has a `null` value in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [SynchronizationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) property **will only return a value when invoked on the main thread**.

If you need to use a [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx31754f.aspx) object in threads *other than the main thread*, you could pass the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx31754f.aspx) instance associated to the main thread to the classes that need it **as a dependency**.

If you choose this solution, you could register the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx31754f.aspx) object obtained from the [SynchronizationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) property on the *main thread* as a *singleton* in your container. That way all requests for a [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx31754f.aspx) from that point on will automatically be satisfied by the container with the singleton:

```
// Must run in the main thread
container.RegisterInstance(SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

Comment: The `SetSynchronizationContext` function call only sets the `SynchronizationContext` for the running thread. Meaning that the second option that you mention, "assign in the main thread", does not have an effect on the other threads. (Wrote a gist to prove that: https://gist.github.com/3225564 )

Comment: @JeanHominal You're absolutely correct, thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer.

Comment: Readers should be aware that in .NET 4.0, SynchronizationContext.Current can be null on the main thread. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621372/. Enrico's suggestion is good to store it away as a singleton in your container early in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an implementation of `SynchronizationContext`for WPF it is not recommended for use. WPF has the `Dispatcher` to [build responsive applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx).

In addition `SynchronizationContext.Current` only has a value if you are on the UI thread. If your logic runs in a background thread `Current` will always be null.

Comment: *" it is not recommended for use"*  Do you have a reference for that?  In a WPF application, **SynchronizationContext.Current** returns an instance of type [DispatcherSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext.aspx) which is a SC that uses the Dispatcher.

Comment: I can only find the [reference for Silverlight](http://wildermuth.com/2009/04/12/For_Now_Don_t_Use_SynchronizationContext_in_Silverlight_2_or_3) but I experienced the same behavior in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be a popular suggestion, but you could lazily create and subscribe to your collection.  Then the first access to NwCustomers from the UI thread will kick everything off correctly.

```
public AlphaProductesVM (){}

public ObservableCollection<Alphabetical_list_of_product> NwCustomers
{
    get { 
          if(_NwCustomers == null)
          {
              _NwCustomers = new ObservableCollection<Alphabetical_list_of_product>();
              var repository = new NorthwindRepository();
                  repository
                  .GetAllProducts()
                  .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                  .Subscribe(AddElement);
          }
          return _NwCustomers; 
    }
}
```

or, if you inject the UI thread's dispatcher into your view model you can subscribe on that in the constructor.

```
              var repository = new NorthwindRepository();
                  repository
                  .GetAllProducts()
                  .ObserveOn(theUIdispatcher)
                  .Subscribe(AddElement);
```