# Any scenario where Task.ContinueWith(..., TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()) would *not* run on the UI thread?

Tags: c#, task, multithreading, synchronizationcontext

We are observing something strange, code like this:

```
var task = new Task(...); // run in the background, do something lengthy work
task.ContinueWith(..., TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
task.Start();
```

The second task there calls an event, which in turn tries to update the GUI, and we get the dreaded cross-thread exception.

Checking `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` from the method in the second task there indicates that it is in fact *not* running on the UI thread.

The code that spawned the tasks *is* running on the UI thread.

Is there any scenario where this will go wrong?

Comment: Why create the task directly instead of running Task.StartNew?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, there can be legitimate reasons for doing this (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx), but  this is not germane to the question.

Comment: Well, I can't repro this, nor have I encountered this situation, or the context becoming null, unless the call to create the tasks wasn't really made in the UI thread in the first place

Comment: The 1st thing I'd do is to check what `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` returns in the debugger. What do you find when you do this?

Comment: @Lasse, did you find the reason or a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, have forgotten to mark the answer as accepted. The problem was .net 4.0 and null synchronization context, so a new context is being created at some point, unrelated to the gui thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you are using .NET 4.0, there is a bug where the `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` on the main thread can become null, and you would experience this problem.  If you can reproduce the problem easily, the first thing to check is if `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null when you call `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

See the details of that problem here: [SynchronizationContext.Current is null in Continuation on the main UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621372/synchronizationcontext-current-is-null-in-continuation-on-the-main-ui-thread/11634544#11634544)

The bug is fixed in .NET 4.5.