# Workaround for issue in .NET 4.0 where SynchronizationContext.Current is null

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

What is a workaround for the issue where the `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null unexpectedly on the main thread in .NET 4.0?  See:

- [SynchronizationContext.Current is null in Continuation on the main UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621372/synchronizationcontext-current-is-null-in-continuation-on-the-main-ui-thread/11634544#11634544)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created several extension methods that matched `ContinueWith` and `StartNew` except that they also take an additional `SyncronizationContext`.  I then use this argument to restore the expected `SynchronizationContext` before executing the action:

Below, I've given examples:

```
public static class TaskExtensionMethods
{
    public static Task ContinueWith_UsingSyncContextWorkaround(this Task task, Action<Task> continuationAction, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler, SynchronizationContext sc)
    {
        Action<Task> actionWithWorkaround = t =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(sc);
            continuationAction(t);
        };

        return task.ContinueWith(actionWithWorkaround, cancellationToken, continuationOptions, scheduler);
    }

    public static Task StartNew_UsingSyncContextWorkaround(this TaskFactory taskFactory, Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler, SynchronizationContext sc)
    {
        Action actionWithWorkaround = () =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(sc);
            action();
        };

        return taskFactory.StartNew(actionWithWorkaround, cancellationToken, creationOptions, scheduler);
    }
}
```

I then use these extension methods in place of `.ContinueWith` or `.StartNew`

**Related Question:**

- [How to create a generic Task.ContinueWith extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391498/how-to-create-a-generic-task-continuewith-extension-method)

Comment: when you say restore the `expected SynchronizationContext` what is the expected SynchronizationContext. Could you give an example of how to use these extensions?

Comment: @user1 I mean restoring current `SynchronizationContext` to what it would be without the bug.  So, for example, in Winforms, the main thread would typically have a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` installed as current.  With the bug, in a continuation the current SynchronizationContext would be null.  With this workaround it will be the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` as it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the workaround works great. Annoying Microsoft closed this bug as could not reproduce. I wonder if they even tried to reproduce it

Comment: @user1, they closed it as "not reproducible" in .NET 4.5 (which is true).  There wasn't a way for me to log the bug against .NET 4.0 since .NET 4.5 was already out at the time.