# How to create a generic Task.ContinueWith extension method

Tags: c#, generics, task-parallel-library

So currently I have a `Task.ContinueWith` extensions method like so:

```
public static Task ContinueWith_UsingSyncContextWorkaround(this Task task, Action<Task> continuationAction, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler, SynchronizationContext sc)
{
    Action<Task> actionWithWorkaround = t =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(sc);
        continuationAction(t);
    };

    return task.ContinueWith(actionWithWorkaround, cancellationToken, continuationOptions, scheduler);
}
```

and this works fine but it doesn't give me access to the result of the `Task` so I would like to create a generic extension method.

I have tried:

```
public static Task<T> ContinueWith_UsingSyncContextWorkaround(this Task<T> task, Action<Task<T>> continuationAction, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler, SynchronizationContext sc)
{
    Action<Task<T>> actionWithWorkaround = t =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(sc);
        continuationAction(t);
    };

    return task.ContinueWith(actionWithWorkaround, cancellationToken, continuationOptions, scheduler);
}
```

But this won't compile because

> The type or namespace name T could not be found

How do I create a generic `Task.ContinueWith` extension method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `T` declaration in the method name. Also your `Action<T>` needs to become a `Func<Task<T>, T>`:

```
public static Task<T> ContinueWithUsingSyncContextWorkaround<T>(this Task<T> task,
                                               Func<Task<T>, T> continuationFunc, 
                                               CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                                               TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions,
                                               TaskScheduler scheduler,
                                               SynchronizationContext sc)
{
    Func<Task<T>, T> funcWithWorkaround = t =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(sc);
        return continuationFunc(t);
    };

    return task.ContinueWith<T>(funcWithWorkaround, cancellationToken,
                                continuationOptions, scheduler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! although I must add there is also another mistake in my code. `Task.ContinueWith` returns `Task` not `Task<T>`

Comment: @user1 Missed that. Edited the answer.

Comment: @user1 BTW - are you using this to set continuations on the UI context?

Comment: I'm using it as a workaround to this issue: [workaround-for-issue-in-net-4-0-where-synchronizationcontext-current-is-null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953281/workaround-for-issue-in-net-4-0-where-synchronizationcontext-current-is-null/20953283#20953283)

Comment: @user1 See my edited answer. You'll need a `Func<Task<T>, T> instead`.

Comment: Could you explain why I need to use `Func<Task<T, T>` using it with `Task<T>` compiles ok

Comment: @user1 How would you return `T` from an `Action`?