# TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext exception when called from worker thread

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Not quite sure what's going on here -

This bit of code is causing issues as it is first called from the Main thread (verified in Task view in VS) and scheduling the tasks, however when setting a breakpoint in `UpdateSearchCache` we're now in the worker thread - no longer main!

Subsequent pieces of UI code being called from there fail as they're executed on the worker thread.

Isn't that the whole point of specifying the scheduler? What am I missing?

This code is called when starting our app. It's called from the Bootstrapper of our PRISM app and running on the **MainThread**.

The `SynchronizationContext.Current` is NOT null when the Task is started.

```
var currentScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
if (ctx == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException();

Task.Factory
    .StartNew(
        () =>
            SearchHelper.CacheSearchResults(_service.GetData())
    .ContinueWith(result => UpdateCache(result.Result), currentScheduler);
```

Comment: Does the first line of your code fragment get executed on the main UI thread? If so, do you do it upon `Form.Load` etc., that is inside the `Application.Run` core loop?

Comment: Yes, it's the main thread.

Comment: Before you save it, do this: `Debug.Assert(SynchronizationContext.Current != null)`. Does it pass?

Comment: You might be running into this problem if you are using .net 4.0: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11621372/495262

Comment: Indeed we are using (and have to) 4.0 :-(

Comment: `SynchronizationContext.Current` is not null when we start - question edited accordingly.

Comment: @Noseratio Erm.. link goes to this very question? ;-)

Comment: @cacau, wrong link, sorry. Meant this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22217477/1768303

Answer (score 3):

`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` throws an `InvalidOperationException` when there is no synchronisation context on the calling thread i.e. `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns null.

Comment: But how come the method is executed on a worker thread when it's supposed to run in the current thread, a.k.a. main?

Comment: @cacau - Which thread the continuation is scheduled on depends on which synchronisation context you have. The default synchronisation context schedules tasks to be run on the thread pool. However if you're getting the exception, the problem occurs before you even start the parent task, and there's not enough code here to see why that might happen.

Comment: This piece of called is called in our (PRISM) bootstrapper right at the startup time of our app. Question edited accordingly. At least in VS we can see a bunch of worker threads plus the main thread exist already at that time..

Comment: @cacau: you are aware that SyncronisationContext.Current is not a global variable, it is a per thread property. You might want to capture the TaskScheduler from UI thread code and use it from the backgruond thread.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan, he does with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. That captures the sync. context at the moment of call, and it's non-null.

Answer (score 1):

Something really weird is going on here. Try the following approach. It's a workaround, but it also may help to diagnose the problem:

```
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
Debug.Assert(dispatcher == Application.Current.Dispatcher);

Task.Factory
    .StartNew(
        () => SearchHelper.CacheSearchResults(_service.GetData()))
    .ContinueWith(result => 
    { 
        // is the app's dispatcher still the same?

        Debug.Assert(dispatcher == Application.Current.Dispatcher);

        // explicitly use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, that's what
        // DispatcherSynchronizationContext does behind the scene

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
            () => UpdateCache(result.Result)));

    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```