# Why a unique synchronization context for each Dispatcher.BeginInvoke callback?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, synchronizationcontext

I've just noticed that with .NET 4.5 each `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`/`InvokeAsync` callback is executed on its own very unique Synchronization Context (an instance of `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`). **What's the reason behind this change?**

The following trivial WPF app illustrates this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Action test = null;
            var i = 0;

            test = () =>
            {
                var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;

                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => 
                {
                    Debug.Print("same context #" + i + ": " +
                        (sc == SynchronizationContext.Current));
                    if ( i < 10 ) 
                    {
                        i++;
                        test();
                    }
                });
            };

            this.Loaded += (s, e) => test();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
same context #0: False
same context #1: False
same context #2: False
...
```

Setting `BaseCompatibilityPreferences.ReuseDispatcherSynchronizationContextInstance` to `true` restores the .NET 4.0 behavior:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        BaseCompatibilityPreferences.ReuseDispatcherSynchronizationContextInstance = true;
    }
}
```

```
same context #0: True
same context #1: True
same context #2: True
...
```

Studying [the .NET sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) for `DispatcherOperation` shows this:

```
[SecurityCritical]
private void InvokeImpl() 
{
    SynchronizationContext oldSynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    try 
    {
        // We are executing under the "foreign" execution context, but the 
        // SynchronizationContext must be for the correct dispatcher. 
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(_dispatcher));

        // Invoke the delegate that does the work for this operation.
        _result = _dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(_method, _args, _isSingleParameter);
    }
    finally 
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(oldSynchronizationContext); 
    } 
}
```

I don't understand why this might be needed, the callbacks queued with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`/`InvokeAsync` are anyway executed on the correct thread which already has an instance of `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` installed on it.

One interesting side effect of this change is that `await TaskCompletionSource.Task` continuation (triggered by `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult`) is almost always asynchronous in .NET 4.5 WPF, unlike with WinForms or v4.0 WPF ([some more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21851153/1768303)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is explained with a very long comment in the source code.  Quoting from the 4.5.1 Reference Source in wpf\src\Base\System\Windows\BaseCompatibilityPreferences.cs:

```
    ///     WPF 4.0 had a performance optimization where it would
    ///     frequently reuse the same instance of the
    ///     DispatcherSynchronizationContext when preparing the
    ///     ExecutionContext for invoking a DispatcherOperation.  This
    ///     had observable impacts on behavior.
    ///
    ///     1) Some task-parallel implementations check the reference
    ///         equality of the SynchronizationContext to determine if the
    ///         completion can be inlined - a significant performance win.
    ///
    ///     2) But, the ExecutionContext would flow the
    ///         SynchronizationContext which could result in the same
    ///         instance of the DispatcherSynchronizationContext being the
    ///         current SynchronizationContext on two different threads.
    ///         The continuations would then be inlined, resulting in code
    ///         running on the wrong thread.
    ///
    ///     In 4.5 we changed this behavior to use a new instance of the
    ///     DispatcherSynchronizationContext for every operation, and
    ///     whenever SynchronizationContext.CreateCopy is called - such
    ///     as when the ExecutionContext is being flowed to another thread.
    ///     This has its own observable impacts:
    ///
    ///     1) Some task-parallel implementations check the reference
    ///         equality of the SynchronizationContext to determine if the
    ///         completion can be inlined - since the instances are
    ///         different, this causes them to resort to the slower
    ///         path for potentially cross-thread completions.
    ///
    ///     2) Some task-parallel implementations implement potentially
    ///         cross-thread completions by callling
    ///         SynchronizationContext.Post and Wait() and an event to be
    ///         signaled.  If this was not a true cross-thread completion,
    ///         but rather just two seperate instances of
    ///         DispatcherSynchronizationContext for the same thread, this
    ///         would result in a deadlock.
```

Or to put it another way, they fixed the bug in your code :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the main reason is that the 4.5 `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` also captures the operation's `DispatcherPriority`, so it cannot be reused (this behavior is also configurable via `BaseCompatibilityPreferences.FlowDispatcherSynchronizationContextPriority`).

Regarding `await` - in `SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation` there's a *referencial* equality for the synchronization context captured by the async method to the *current* one (returned by `SynchronizationContext.CurrentNoFlow`), which of course fails if the context isn't reused. So the operation to gets queued on the dispatcher instead of being executed inline.

This also affects `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`, which also performs a referencial equality check.

It's a bit puzzling they actively chose to make async continuations slower in some cases. Couldn't they change the behavior to allow comparing the sync context's for equality (for example, by overriding `Equals` and checking it belongs to the same Dispatcher)? Maybe it's worth opening a Connect issue.

Comment: A very interesting observation, thank you. I wish I could mark both answers.

Comment: In fact, this point from their comment doesn't seem to be right: *"...But, the ExecutionContext would flow the SynchronizationContext which could result in the same instance of the DispatcherSynchronizationContext being the current SynchronizationContext on two different threads"*. This only happens if the `ExecutionContext` is **explictly** flowed with `ExecutionContext.Run`. Otherwise, synchronization context doesn't get flowed when a thread switch occurs (unlike, say, `CallContext`).  Some more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17242222/1768303).

Comment: This is a really annoying design choice! I have a Task Invoking manager which can chose different Dispather Priority contexts but it has no way to check whether the current active DispatcherSynchrnonisationContext is ok to use because the DispatcherPriority is a private field. Grrrrrr!! Using reflection to check this will lose all the performance benefits of not doing a Task Context switch on every async call. Very puzzling.