# SynchronizationContext.Current in async callback

Tags: wpf, winforms, asynchronous, synchronizationcontext

I am using `SynchronizationContext` as a means to synchronize to the GUI thread, for WinForms and WPF. Recently I ran into an issue with the old style async callbacks:

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        var cl = new TcpClient();
        cl.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1", 22222, ConnectedCallback, null);
    }
    public void ConnectedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current != uiContext)
            uiContext.Post(x => MyUIOperation(), null);
        else
            MyUIOperation();
    }

    public void MyUIOperation()
    {
        Title = "Connected";
    }

    private SynchronizationContext uiContext;
```

This will throw an exception, because the `SynchronizationContext.Current` in the callback function is equal to the captured one, and therefore the UI operation is executed in the worker thread of the callback.

Using this exact same code in WinForms works as I had expected.

For now as a workaround, I am capturing the current `ManagedThreadId` instead and compare it in the callback. What is correct way to handle this?

Update:

I should add that I am modifying a very old existing class that currently uses the following construct:

```
if (control.InvokeRequired())
    control.BeginInvoke(SomeFunction);
else
    SomeFunction();
```

I am trying to remove the WinForms dependency, without having much impact on the clients of this class. The `SomeFunction()` is raising events, so if I just call uiContext.Send() or uiContext.Post() , the order of execution is changed since Post() will always queue the call, and Send() will always block.

Also, this is just a very small piece of code to show the root of my issue. In reality the function doing the Post() can be called from the main thread.

This is targeting .NET 4.0

Comment: I would say creating a service which ensures and gives you the UI sync context is the way to go. Then always inject that service to any code part you need and call the Post on Context without any checks everywhere where you need to be sure it is executed on foreground.

Comment: Can you post the exact message and stack trace of the exception you are getting?

Comment: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.Window.set_Title(String value)
   at WpfApplication2.MainWindow.MyUIOperation()

Comment: Why do you need to check `if (SynchronizationContext.Current != uiContext)`? Why not to always invoke `Post`?

Comment: Because in my case, the call to `MyUIOperation()` function would need to be called immediately if the `ConnectedCallback` function is called from the main thread. If I use `Post()` that does not happen, the call is always deferred. This is just a very trimmed down example to illustrate that in the case of `ConnectedCallback`, the `SynchronizationContext.Current` is the same as it was in the main thread. So simulating `Control.InvokeRequired` does not seem to work in WPF, the way I do it in the code. But it does in WinForms.

Comment: The code you posted should work.

Comment: ConnectedCallback is never called on the UI thread. I think you are solving a non-existing problem. Also, you should be using await instead. The APM pattern is obsolete.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post to be more clear. My main issue is really that I was always under the impression that when you capture the SynchronizationContext in the main thread, it will always be different from the SynchronizationContext.Current of other threads. This does not seem to be the case, so it can't be used to replace a "InvokeRequired" without changing the behavior of the class.

Comment: @Night94: There should not be a UI SyncCtx on a background thread, unless that background thread does something it shouldn't do like create a UI object. Can you post a minimal reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @StephenCleary I can attest that `SynchronizationContext.Current` from inside the callback is the same reference as `uiContext`. Tried it on Win8.1 x64, targeting .NET 4.0. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B91vNcnuPv_GNE10Z3doOEtvSms/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because in my case, the call to MyUIOperation() function would need to
>   be called immediately if the ConnectedCallback function is called from
>   the main thread.

That means the call to `MyUIOperation()` would be a blocking call if the `ConnectedCallback` is invoked in the UI thread, as opposed to non-blocking if it is invoked from the another thread. This non-determinism could cause other problems down the road.

Just call [`Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx) instead. According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/gg598924.aspx), the call to `Send` would just invoke the delegate directly if already in the UI thread.

Also, you could just do [`Dispatcher.Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) instead.

Comment: See my update. I understand that I can use either Send or Post for synchronization and I agree that the original design was bad to begin with. However in order to not cause a chain reaction of other bad things the logic needs to be "If I am running in the UI thread, call this function immediately, otherwise queue the call", and I would like to use SynchronizationContext and nothing UI framework specific

Comment: I understand. In that case, I don't see any good solution other than the workaround that you are already using. I'm not sure whether `SynchronizationContext.Current` is supposed to be different for each thread. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) says "this is useful for propagating a synchronization context from one thread to another", so I'd say it is shared between threads. You could use `Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground` instead of `SynchronizationContext.Current != uiContext`, but I wouldn't rely on it either.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out, in .NET 4.5 the `SynchronizationContext` is in fact different in the callback function and the if statement would evaluate to true. This was a deliberate change, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217477/why-a-unique-synchronization-context-for-each-dispatcher-begininvoke-callback)

> ```
>    WPF 4.0 had a performance optimization where it would
>      frequently reuse the same instance of the
>      DispatcherSynchronizationContext when preparing the
>      ExecutionContext for invoking a DispatcherOperation.  This
>      had observable impacts on behavior.
>      1) Some task-parallel implementations check the reference
>          equality of the SynchronizationContext to determine if the
>          completion can be inlined - a significant performance win.
>      2) But, the ExecutionContext would flow the
>          SynchronizationContext which could result in the same
>          instance of the DispatcherSynchronizationContext being the
>          current SynchronizationContext on two different threads.
>          The continuations would then be inlined, resulting in code
>          running on the wrong thread.
> ```